# Workaround for passing parameter to jQuery ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code called on jQuery document.ready() which is used in multiple HTML files. Now the difference is each of these HTMLs uses a different div id. 
I know one option is to just check for hardcode div ids inside $(document).ready() . But I wanted to write a generic code which would take the div Ids based on the currrent/calling HTML page?

So is there any way or workaround for passing parameter to jQuery ready() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document ready just takes in an handler function as a parameter.
You can still define a generic code in you document ready function, by storing the current div id for each html.

```
<input type="hidden" id="current_div" value="div1" />

$(document).ready(function() {  
    var div_id = $('#current_div').val();  
    // generic code  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(document).ready()` just wants a function as an argument so you can write a function that takes your ID as an argument and returns a function for `$(document).ready()`. For example, instead of this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some_id').click(/*...*/);
});
```

you could do this:

```
function make_ready(id) {
    return function() {
        $('#' + id).click(/*...*/);
    };
}

$(document).ready(make_ready('some_id'));
```

Then you could put your `make_ready` in some common location and use it to build the functions for your `$(document).ready()` calls.

Comment: I prefer this solution, as it is also a nice illustrates the beauty of closure.

Comment: I agree with you @SahilTandon (oddly enough). Functions are first class citizens in the JavaScript world so why not use them?